# Convert outline into todos/checkboxes

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, todo

If I have outline structure like this:

```
* Tasks
** First
** Second
** Third
** etc
```

is there a simple way to turn all tasks into TODO items or checkboxes? I can of course use `replace-string` but maybe there's already a keybinding, since maybe it's seems to be done quite often?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a built-in function for that, but you can create one and bind it yourself. I wrote this one, that will replace all outlines in region with `- [ ]`. If no region is active, replace the outline in current line.

```
(defun org-outline-to-checkbox ()
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (replace-regexp "^*+" "- [ ]" nil (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (replace-regexp "^*+" "- [ ]" nil
                    (line-beginning-position)
                    (line-end-position))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's discuss low-level command that you need. [`org-todo`](http://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-basics.html#index-org_002dtodo-539) cycles the headline your cursor is on through TODO states. [`org-toggle-item`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html#index-C_002dc-_002d-222) turns headlines into lists, [`org-toggle-heading`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-editing.html#Structure-editing) turns lists into headlines. In standard Emacs they are mapped to <kbd>C-c C-t</kbd>, <kbd>C-c -</kbd>, <kbd>C-c *</kbd> respectively.

`org-todo` doesn't work on regions, but it would be cool if we could put a TODO state on every heading that doesn't have a TODO (and doesn't have other states, including DONE). This is how we would do that.

```
(defun outline-to-checkboxes (from to)
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (with-undo-collapse
        (narrow-to-region from to)
        (end-of-buffer)
        (while (outline-previous-heading)
          (when (null (org-get-todo-state))
            (org-todo "TODO")))))))
```

The reason I go to the end of buffer and apply `outline-previous-heading` instead of going from top forward is described in a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13349772/596361): `while` always calls the first argument at least once, and if you started at the beginning of your buffer starts with an Org heading, you'll skip it.

[`with-undo-collapse`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7560/3972) is a custom macro that allows you to undo the whole change in one action (follow the link to get the code).

Unfortunately, due to a [bug](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2016-07/msg00041.html) in `org-toggle-list`, changing headings to a list with checkboxes programmatically is difficult, so just go with the regex approach in Jesse's answer.