# Evil mode: How to run evil-indent on the text I've just pasted

Tags: evil, copy-paste, keyboard-macros, vim-emulation

When I copy line three below in evil-mode

```
function foo() {
}
var bar; #copy
```

and paste it at line two, I get

```
function foo() {
var bar; #paste
}
```

instead of the correctly indented

```
function foo() {
  var bar; #paste
}
```

I'd like to automatically indent my newly-pasted lines of code, and in vim, the fix for this is to remap the `p` key to "nnoremap gp p`[v`]=".

I figured that I could use the following in my `init.el` file to replicate the behaviour:

```
(fset 'paste-and-indent
  "p`[v`]=")
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "p") 'paste-and-indent)
```

But when I try to use the code, upon pressing `p` I get `"After 0 kbd macro iterations: Lisp nesting exceeds 'max-lisp-eval-depth'."` I'm confused by this, as `max-lisp-eval-depth` is set to `800`!

Can anyone offer advice on how to implement this behaviour in evil-mode emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a perfect solution, but it's the best I've found so far:

```
(fset 'indent-pasted-text
  "`[v`]=")
... 
(evil-leader/set-key
  "p" 'indent-pasted-text
```

This setup means that after pasting, I can hit `<leader>p` to correctly indent the text. I'm sure there's a better solution, and if you have one feel free to share it—I'll accept your answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using `evil-indent` and `evil-get-marker`.

This uses emacs-29's [`with-undo-amagamate` macro](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/54412/2418) so the operation doesn't create multiple undo entries.

```el
(defun paste-and-indent-after ()
  (interactive)
  (with-undo-amagamate
    (evil-paste-after 1)
    (evil-indent (evil-get-marker ?\[) (evil-get-marker ?\]))))
(defun paste-and-indent-before ()
  (interactive)
  (with-undo-amagamate
    (evil-paste-before 1)
    (evil-indent (evil-get-marker ?\[) (evil-get-marker ?\]))))

;; Bindings for evil leader
(evil-leader/set-key "p" 'paste-and-indent-after)
(evil-leader/set-key "P" 'paste-and-indent-before)
```

---

Note that I couldn't get other answers here working.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a text object based on the fact that `(point)` and `(mark)` are set after a past.

```
(define-key evil-inner-text-objects-map (kbd "P") 'my-evil-pasted-region)

(evil-define-text-object my-evil-pasted-region (count &optional beg end type)
  "Select region that was pasted"
  (evil-range (point) (mark)))
```

Then `>iP` will indent the last pasted region.

Answer (score -1):

Your solution failed because it has unbounded recursion; the first thing it does is call whatever is bound to the "p" key, which is itself. Try something like this instead:

```
(defun paste-and-indent ()
  (interactive)
  (evil-paste-after 0)
  (indent-region))
```

Comment: So if I unbind the `p` key first, it should work?

Comment: If you unbind the 'p' key then it won't call anything at all; that won't help you.

Comment: I see. I've tried the above function, but it gives me `Wrong type argument: commandp, paste-and-indent`

Comment: Sorry, that's what I get for typing this into a textbox instead of into Emacs iteself.

Comment: Ok, now it says `Wrong number of arguments: (2 . 3), 0`.

Comment: I've got it! You just bind `'evil-paste-after` to a key other than `p`, then it works. e.g. 
  `(evil-define-key 'normal global-map (kbd "|")  'evil-paste-after)
  (fset 'paste-and-indent
      "|\`[v\`]=")
  (evil-define-key 'normal global-map (kbd "p")  'paste-and-indent)`

A hack, but a functional hack. Thank for for explaining the problem with recursion to me, or else I wouldn't have found it.

Comment: Scratch that; it causes too many problems. It breaks `put-from-clipboard`, and emacs thinks `p` is two events (it requires two `u` to undo). If you hit `10 p`, that requires 20 `u` to undo. So if you have any further advice on how to write this function properly, I'd really appreciate it.