# Why isn't the jch's "with-undo-collapse" macro an emacs built-in yet?

Tags: undo

I wondered why the [jch](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2223/jch)'s [`with-undo-collapse`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7560/15606) macro (or something like that) isn't an emacs built-in yet.

Is it safe enough? Is there a built-in alternative?

I mean something that can be applied like in the jcs's example of usage:

```el
(defun test-no-collapse ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "toto")
  (undo-boundary)
  (insert "titi"))

(defun test-collapse ()
  (interactive)
  (with-undo-collapse
    (insert "toto")
    (undo-boundary)
    (insert "titi")))
```

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug` as a feature request.  Things don't get built-in if no one asks for them.

Comment: @phils Thank you. I'll do it soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `undo-amalgamate-change-group` nowadays.  Used for instance in the function `viper-adjust-undo` in the file `lisp/emulators/viper-cmd.el`:

```
(defun test-collapse ()
  (let ((cg (prepare-change-group)))
    (insert "toto")
    (undo-boundary)
    (insert "titi")
    (undo-amalgamate-change-group cg)))
```

Comment: Could you please post a concrete example of usage of this function using the above`test-collapse` code? I have some difficulty understanding the `undo-amalgamate-change-group` usage.

Comment: It would be nice to write an `with-undo-collapse` macro that uses `undo-amalgamate-change-group`, since it's more verbose with explicit change-group references.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs 28 has a built-in macro [with-undo-amalgamate](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=5861b8d027382ecbd4c0d3dffc283b8ac95b5692).